# Installing 64-Bit VM on a hyper-v installed on 32 bit machine

Tags: virtualization, virtual-machine, hyper-v, microsoft-virtualization

Is it possible to install **64-Bit** VM on a **hyper-v** installed on 32 bit machine ? If not is there any trick(like emulator) for doing this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't install Hyper-V on a 32-bit machine. 
Hyper-V is only available in x64 editions of Windows Server 2008 and Windows Server 2008 R2.

Comment: Yes, I knew I cannot install it on 32-bit machine, but I wonder it can be virtualized to be in 32-bits machine?

Comment: @thethanghn - Not quite sure what you you are asking, but if you were asking if you can install 32-bit OSes onto the Virtual machines, then the answer is yes.